# Lots of crashes and blue screen of death

Tags: windows-10, bsod, crash

My computer has been crashing a lot lately. All drivers updated, Windows reinstalled. But I still get blue screens of death.

Here's a screenshot from BlueScreenView but it doesn't show any problems here. Crash address was the same for all dumps.

memtest - 0 errors

seatools - 0 errors

[image]

> [image]

Crash address was the same for all dumps

> [image]

Here is WinDbg screenshot. Maybe it will be usefull

> [image]

Comment: `nvlddmkm` is an nVidia driver. Have you tried a clean install of your GeForce drivers?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, newest drivers.  I tried to use an older driver, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you upgrade them, or choose the `clean install` option?

Comment: @spikey_richie both variants

Comment: Is your GPU cool enough? (no pun intended)  You don't mention laptop or not but if desktop, do you have onboard video?  If so, remove the Gfx card and run off onboard long enough to isolate the problem.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It is laptop. It's pretty old, but work well for some time

Comment: Why do you sort in BlueScreenView the entries by Filename? Please sort by "Address ln Stack", or even better - post the `.dbg` file online (OneDrivem Dropbox etc.)

Comment: @harrymc screenshot added

Comment: The crash is caused by the video driver (DirectX Graphics). What is your video card and which driver is installed? What is the computer model?

Comment: do you have iCue; Corsair link; easytune; any other kind of "enthusiast googaw" software installed?

Comment: @harrymc PC: Lenovo Ideapad y700 15-ISK, Video Card: Nvidia GTX 960M, Driver: 497.09 (newest for my card)

Comment: @Yorik No, just programms with what i never had problems before and programs for diagnostic. I don’t have too much programs on my laptop

Comment: It would be helpful to see the value of the parameters, in particular param 1.

Comment: @HelpingHand BlueScreenViewer system files with problems  you mean or dump properties?

Comment: The column in blue screen view is fine. It needs expanding.

Comment: @HelpingHand https://imgur.com/gallery/mPCcVXO. I guess that's what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bug Check 0x113: VIDEO_DXGKRNL_FATAL_ERROR
The VIDEO_DXGKRNL_FATAL_ERROR bug check has a value of 0x00000113. This indicates that the Microsoft DirectX graphics kernel subsystem has detected a violation.

This bug check appears very infrequently.
```

and

```
Bug Check 0x119: VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR
The VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR bug check has a value of 0x00000119. This indicates that the video scheduler has detected a fatal violation.


Important This topic is for programmers. If you are a customer who has received a blue screen error code while using your computer, see Troubleshoot blue screen errors.

VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR Parameters
The following parameters are displayed on the blue screen. Parameter 1 is the only parameter of interest and identifies the exact violation.

Parameter 1 Cause of Error 
0x1
 The driver has reported an invalid fence ID. 
 
0x2
 The driver failed upon the submission of a command. 
 
0x3
 The driver failed upon patching the command buffer. 
 
0x4
 The driver reported an invalid flip capability.
```

Update drivers and if that doesn't help replace the video card.

Comment: Try running from USB, either WinPE (Win RE) with some applications installed or Ubuntu Live. If either work well and do not crash, then it's almost certainly Windows OS (or possibly the HDD) at fault.